# regex in sed for search & replace

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to replace a string in a line with shell and regex.

For example, in file `config.php` I would like to replace `TO_REPLACE` with `OK_REPLACED`:

```
home/TO_REPLACE/dmwebolabo;
```

I tried this command:

```
sed -i 's/^\(home\/\)[^\/]*\/dmwebolabo/\1OK_REPLACED\/dmwebolabo/g' config.php;
```

but it didn't work. Any help please?

Comment: *It didnt work* what is the error that you are getting.

Comment: No error but just TO_REPLACE is not replaced with OK_REPLACED in the file config.php

Comment: Do you have required permissions to modify the file. The `sed` command is correct, works fine for me

Comment: Which terminal software you use has no bearing on `sed`'s syntax.

Comment: The `sed` command works for me also.

Comment: Hello Thanks for all of you 
I see better now the problem 
When I put home/TO_REPLACE/dmwebolabo alone it works fine but when it's in its original line it doesn't 
This is the original line :
`define('UPLOAD_DIRECTORY', '' . DS . 'home/TO_REPLACE/dmwebolabo' . DS);`

Comment: Do you get an error message? Which OS?

Comment: No message error I'm on Linux with putty SSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your statement from the comments:

`Hello Thanks for all of you I see better now the problem When I put home/TO_REPLACE/dmwebolabo alone it works fine but when it's in its original line it doesn't This is the original line : define('UPLOAD_DIRECTORY', '' . DS . 'home/TO_REPLACE/dmwebolabo' . DS);`

The problem looks like your regex:

```
^\(home\/\)[^\/]*\/dmwebolabo
```

is anchored `^` to the beginning of the string. Try removing the anchor.

```
\(home\/\)[^\/]*\/dmwebolabo
```

Comment: Now I'm dealing with `public $user = 'TO_REPLACE';`

`sed -i "s/^\(public \$user = *')[^']*'/\1OK_REPLACED'/g" configuration.php`

Didn't work :(

Comment: Could you help me here please? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963384/regex-in-sed-for-search-replace-invalid-reference
I will be glad to choose your answer as the best one ;)