# regex in sed for search & replace (invalid reference)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to replace a string in a line with shell and regex.

For example, in file `configuration.php` I would like to replace `TO_REPLACE` with `OK_REPLACED`:

```
public $user = 'TO_REPLACE';
```

I tried this command:

```
cd ~/public_html; sed -i "s/^\public $user = *'[^']*'/\1OK_REPLACED'/g" configuration.php
```

but I get this error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 39: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

I also tried this one but nothing

```
sed -i "s/^\(public \$user = *')[^']*'/\1OK_REPLACED'/g" configuration.php
```

Answer (score 1):

`\1` in the replacement is replaced with whatever matched the first capture group in the regexp, but you have no capture groups. You need to put capture groups around the parts of the original line that you want to copy into the replacement.

```
sed -i "s/^\(public \$user = *')[^']*'/\1OK_REPLACED'/g" configuration.php
```

If you want to replace all occurrences of `TO_REPLACE`, you can just do:

```
sed -i 's/TO_REPLACE/OK_REPLACED/g' configuration.php
```

Comment: Hello thank you very much 
Now with the new command I get : `sed: -e expression #1, char 44: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS`

Comment: I don't understand why. `\1` gets the `public` part, and `\2` gets everything matching `= *'[^']*'`

Comment: Hello,
You can please change the code as you like 
I would like just to replace `TO_REPLACE` with `OK_REPLACED`

Comment: Hello Barmar and thank you ;)
For the edited command no error message but nothing changed 
For the second I get :
`sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`

Comment: Oh, I was very confused. I thought `$user` was a bash variable containing the name you wanted to replace. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I think your parenthesis must be balanced. Your first one is prefixed with a backslash, but the 2nd one is not. Try this:

```
sed -i "s/^\(public \$user = *'\)[^']*'/\1OK_REPLACED'/g" configuration.php
```

or this:

```
sed -r -i "s/^(public \$user = *')[^']*'/\1OK_REPLACED'/g" configuration.php
```

Comment: This should solves your undefined reference problem. Yet I do not check anything else.. (Post it if further problems occur and you can not resolve it.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to "group" put parenthesis around the piece of the expression that you need to substitute for "\1": in this case everything before the first "'".

Comment: Hello thank you 
Could you please make me an example?
I tried several possibilities but nothing :(

Comment: I would do something like this: sed "s/\(public \$user = '\)[^']*\('\)/\1OK_REPLACED\2/g"